# The middle coefficient of a cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: number-theory

It is known that the middle coefficient of a cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi _n$, with $n\geq 3$, is $0$ (when $n$ is a power of 2) or an odd integer. Is it known just what odd integers can occur?

Comment: I note that the result OP quotes can be found in Gregory P Dresden, On the middle coefficient of a cyclotomic polynomial, Amer Math Monthly 111 (2004) 531-533.

Comment: Note also http://oeis.org/A095878 and http://oeis.org/A095877